SalesForce API failed (Status: 400) & SalesForce API failed (Unauthorized): What do the error codes indicate is the problem?
We have a WordPress site and we're using a SalesForce API.
There are two specific errors that I received emails about. Can anyone shed any light on what may be the problem?

SalesForce API failed (Unauthorized): 
a:1:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:7:"message";s:26:"Session expired or invalid";s:9:"errorCode";s:18:"INVALID_SESSION_ID";}}

SalesForce API failed (Status: 400)
a:2:{s:5:"error";s:13:"invalid_grant";s:17:"error_description";s:22:"authentication failure";}


If anyone has any suggestions for how to fix it as well, that would be great - even if it's just a hint as to what to look at, or what to investigate further.
For context, also the API seems to have stopped working when we migrated our website hosting to AWS with a Bedrock structure (as opposed to the standard WordPress).  But our website is still on WordPress.
Things preventing me from solving: quite frankly just lack of experience and knowledge!
What I tried: to be honest, nothing because this is something I don't understand well at all. I am just looking for some hints as to what may be going on! I'm working with more experienced developers, but I want to try and be proactive and get some info. It's been like this for over a year!!

I would talk to your developers. What you posted here is all they would really need to focus here. Nice of you to be proactive, but unnecessary. Basically, without access to the site, we can only guess. That said, those errors are saying that authentication to the API is failing. There could be something stopping the API credentials from passing to Salesforce (like a cached/deferred JavaScript file) or  or their could be some configuration in Salesforce that needs to be updated.

You probably have a dedicated Salesforce user account whom the integration runs as. Username and password might be written in your wordpress plugin's config, php.ini or even hardcoded (ugh), I don't know enough about WP to help with that.
So trying to attack it from Salesforce side... Do you know what the integration does? Does it just read data from Salesforce or also create some (say Cases or maybe Leads? - you could look at Case "Created By" user). When all else fails you could try searching for "api user", "integration user", "mr wordpress" or maybe you'll spot some errors in Setup -> Login History.
Once you have the user record - go to it's setup page in Salesforce and scroll all the way down to login history. Chances are there will be errors. User is inactive. Password expired. Wrong "security token"... Maybe not a trusted IP anymore (if it crashed just after migration it sounds like your Salesforce is configured to allow logins only from certain pool of IP addresses and AWS is not on the list. Your SF admin would have to adjust or abandon whitelisting by IP). Maybe the user is active but got demoted, it doesn't have "API access" permission anymore?
I don't know how good the WP plugin author was, gut feel is they used the insecure "username password flow". There are better methods (OAuth2) where password isn't written in WP, admin authorises once, types the pass on real Salesforce login screen and afterwards "access_token", "refresh_token" are used - it's more secure but maybe the tokens expired and need to be reauthenticated...
